# v.getParent within OnClick within onClickListener causes runtime failure

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am developing an android app, using eclipse IDE, part of which reads data through a remote gateway, and the information is then presented as a table - using TableLayout and TableRow, dynamically in Java. I want to be able to show the data and then select an element, and based on this, carry out some other actions.

The extract of data, and the generation of the screen and the list works fine. I have set it to be clickable, and set an appropriate onClickListener. I am able to get into the onClick method (Proven by having output with v.getId()) - (seen on the LogCat of the Eclipse IDE), within the onClickListener. However when trying to v.getParent within the onClick method, the Eclipse emulator fails. The error message shown after the VM shuts down shows :

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow.

I have spent a couple of days trying to identify problem, but obviously don't understand what I have wrong, so am reaching out for help.  Whether this is a nudge in the right direction, or specifically telling me what is wrong,  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ultimately I would like to extract one of the fields in the TableRow (node) - which is a unique integer address, and use this for further processing.

Java Code is :

```
public void readNodeKeys(int[] value) {

setContentView(R.layout.testrz_nodes);

TabHost node_host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
node_host.setup();     

TabSpec nodeTab = node_host.newTabSpec("node_tabs");
nodeTab.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.node_information),
        getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on));
nodeTab.setContent(R.id.node_ScrollView2);
node_host.addTab(nodeTab);

node_host.setCurrentTabByTag("node_tabs");

TableLayout list_table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.node_TableLayout2);

initializeHeaderRow(list_table);

        try {
            processScores(list_table, value);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to load list status data", e);
    }
}

public void initializeHeaderRow(TableLayout statusTable) {
      TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
      int textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.testrz_logo_color);
      float textSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.testrz_nodelist_text_size_6);
      addTextToRowWithValues(headerRow, getResources().getString(R.string.testrz_nodelist_node), textColor, textSize);
      addTextToRowWithValues(headerRow, getResources().getString(R.string.testrz_nodelist_data_index), textColor, textSize);
      addTextToRowWithValues(headerRow, getResources().getString(R.string.testrz_nodelist_zone_A), textColor, textSize);
      addTextToRowWithValues(headerRow, getResources().getString(R.string.testrz_nodelist_zone_B), textColor, textSize);
      addTextToRowWithValues(headerRow, getResources().getString(R.string.testrz_nodelist_zone_C), textColor, textSize);
      addTextToRowWithValues(headerRow, getResources().getString(R.string.testrz_nodelist_module_type), textColor, textSize);
      statusTable.addView(headerRow);
}

public void addTextToRowWithValues(final TableRow tableRow, String text, int textColor, float textSize) {

      TextView textView = new TextView(this);
      textView.setTextSize(textSize);
      textView.setTextColor(textColor);
      textView.setText(text);

      tableRow.setClickable(true);
      tableRow.setOnClickListener(tableRowOnClickListener);
      tableRow.addView(textView);                               

}

    public OnClickListener tableRowOnClickListener = new OnClickListener () {

    public void onClick(View v) {               

    System.out.println("Row Clicked : " + v.getId());

    TableRow tr = (TableRow)v.getParent();
    System.out.println("We've got to the TableRow tr");

    TextView tv = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(index);
    System.out.println("We've got to the TableView tv");

    String result = tv.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("On Click string is : " + result);
    }
};

public void processScores(final TableLayout statusTable, int[] value) throws 
    IOException {

    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("mtestrz_Node_Count : " + Integer.toHexString(mtestrz_Node_Count));

    for (counter = 0; counter < mtestrz_Node_Count; counter++) {

    testrz_Node_Key_Values RNKV = new testrz_Node_Key_Values();

    offset = 0x10;

    while (value[(counter * offset)+18] != 0xff) {

    int eventType = -1;
    boolean bFoundScores = false;

// Find list

    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][0] = value[(counter * offset)+18];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][1] = value[(counter * offset)+19];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][2] = value[(counter * offset)+20];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][3] = value[(counter * offset)+21];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][4] = value[(counter * offset)+22];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][5] = value[(counter * offset)+23];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][6] = value[(counter * offset)+24];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][7] = value[(counter * offset)+25];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][8] = value[(counter * offset)+26];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][9] = value[(counter * offset)+27];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][10] = value[(counter * offset)+28];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][11] = value[(counter * offset)+29];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][12] = value[(counter * offset)+30];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][13] = value[(counter * offset)+31];                                
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][14] = value[(counter * offset)+32];
    nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][15] = value[(counter * offset)+33];


    RNKV.Node_add = nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][1] * 0x100 + nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][0];
    RNKV.Code_Control = nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][3] * 0x100 + nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][2];
    RNKV.Data_index = nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][5] * 0x100 + nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][4];
    RNKV.Zone_A = nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][7] * 0x100 + nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][6];
    RNKV.Zone_B = nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][9] * 0x100 + nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][8];
    RNKV.Zone_C = nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][11] * 0x100 + nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][10];
    RNKV.Module_type = nodelist[mtestrz_Node_Count][12];

        Module_Type module_str;
        module_str = (module_type_str[RNKV.Module_type]);
        String module_string;
        module_string = module_str.toString();

        bFoundScores = true;
        String node = Integer.toHexString(RNKV.Node_add);
        String data_index = Integer.toHexString(RNKV.Data_index);
        String Zone_A = Integer.toHexString(RNKV.Zone_A);
        String Zone_B = Integer.toHexString(RNKV.Zone_B);
        String Zone_C = Integer.toHexString(RNKV.Zone_C);
        String module_type = module_string;
        insertStatusRow(statusTable, node, data_index, Zone_A, Zone_B, Zone_C, module_type);

// Handle no scores available

        if (bFoundScores == false) {
        final TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        TextView noResults = new TextView(this);
        noResults.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.testrz_no_data));
        newRow.addView(noResults);
        statusTable.addView(newRow);
        }

        counter = counter + 1;

    }
                            }
                        }
public void insertStatusRow(final TableLayout statusTable, String node, String data_index, String Zone_A, String Zone_B, String Zone_C, String module_type) {
    final TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
    int textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.testrz_title_color);
    float textSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.testrz_nodelist_text_size_6);
    addTextToRowWithValues(newRow, node, textColor, textSize);
    addTextToRowWithValues(newRow, data_index, textColor, textSize);
    addTextToRowWithValues(newRow, Zone_A, textColor, textSize);
    addTextToRowWithValues(newRow, Zone_B, textColor, textSize);
    addTextToRowWithValues(newRow, Zone_C, textColor, textSize);
    addTextToRowWithValues(newRow, module_type, textColor, textSize);

    statusTable.addView(newRow);
    }
```

XML Code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/rayzig_nodes_RelativeLayout02"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rayzig_nodes_Textview02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/nodes" />

<DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/rayzig_nodes_digitalClock2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rayzig_nodes_Textview02"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/clock" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ScrollView 
                android:id="@+id/node_ScrollView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/node_TableLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" >

                </TableLayout>

             </ScrollView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried any of the answer?

Comment: I have commented on each of the response I have had, following trying out the ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Onclick listner is an anonymous inner class,

So try this inside your onclick:

```
 View parent = (View)v.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        TableRow tr = parent.findViewById(R.id.parent);//your xml resource

    }
```

Comment: I tried this in the onClick method, but found it made no difference. However, having found I also had a problem with the v.getId() earlier in the method, because I hadn't set the Id in the TableRow when setting up the table I found i was able to get the info I needed just using that, as I had a unique field that I could use as the Id, which happened to be the field I needed for on going activities.

Answer (score 0):

tablerow parant is tableLayout so change this like

```
TableLayout tablelayout= (TableLayout )v.getParent();
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had to change the code in the onClicK method to include TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)v.getPatent(); and also the TableRow tr = (TableRow)tl.getChildAt(index); TextView tv = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(index); String result = tv.getText().toString(); which then gave the result I was looking for. However, it showed me some other issues, which related to the v.getId() because I hadn't set the id for the tableRow in the earlier method.